# How to draw image in a tkinter canvas after calling mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

**Long story short**: I want to draw an image in a `tkinter.Canvas` on a button click. Obviously, this will happen after calling `mainloop()`. However, `create_image()` function is not updating the canvas.

**Long Story**:
I'm trying to draw several images in a `tkinter.Canvas` on a button click. This is roughly my code.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage


# this code is inside an event handler of a button click
# this is also a class-method
ROW_COUNT = 1
COL_COUNT = 3
for i in range(ROW_COUNT):
    for j in range(COL_COUNT):
        raw_img = Image.open(img_list[i * COL_COUNT + j])
        resized_img = raw_img.resize((160, 160), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = PhotoImage(resized_img)
        x = j * 170
        y = i * 170
        self.canvas.create_image(x, y, anchor=NW, image=img)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
```

As this code executes on a button click, this will surely be after calling `mainloop()`. However, nothing happens after the execution of this code. If I recall `mainloop()` after the loops, only the last image gets drawn. If I call `mainloop()` in the inner loop, only the first image gets drawn (and probably both the loops breaks).

How can I draw all the images?

Comment: I don't see any code where you actually draw something. Oh yea; the code doesn't run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, did I misunderstand completely? You want to initiate an action after mainloop has started? In that case you should use `bind`. Check out [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and then google for examples.

Comment: You need to save references to the images you are creating - otherwise, they get garbage collected and vanish from your widget.  Appending them to a global list would be a reasonable solution here, assuming that the images will remain through the rest of the program's execution.